# how to get id while parsing the json using recursion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Can you please tell me how to get ID  of all children while parsing the json.

I using recursion function But it is call infinite time..

here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ds8vQ/

```
for(var i=0;i<json.children.length;i++){
    console.log(json.children[i].id);
    recusionGet(json.children[i]);
}
function recusionGet(obj){
    console.log(obj)
    if(typeof(obj.children)!="undefined"){
        // alert('--')
        for(var i=0;i<obj.children.length;i++){
            console.log(json.children[i].id);
            recusionGet(json.children[i]);
        }
    }
}

b
  b-a-1
  b-b-2
     b-b-a
     b-b-b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are parsing object and NOT JSON.
2. Here is [Answer](http://jsbin.com/teyujemo/1/edit?js,console)

Code sample

```
var idLine = "";
recusionGet(json);
function recusionGet(object){
    for (var elem in object ){
        if(typeof(object[elem]) == "object"){
            recusionGet(object[elem]);
        }
        if(elem == "id"){
            idLine += object[elem] + "|";
        }
    }     
}
console.log(idLine);
```

Comment: your answer is not visible can you use fiddle

Comment: thanks your answer is correct..can we add some special character  so that it will clearly show which node have how may child

Comment: You can't get length of an object without it's iterating

Comment: why you are now using children.length concept ? why i am not getting answer

Comment: Actually If I am parsing object .Why we can use children concept ?Actually my real motive is not to print ID.

Comment: why real requirement is take first node of children array then go deep till children array don't have child

Comment: can we make demo while using children.length concept